# How do I find records based on month-name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
select dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total
from CLOI_ClientOrderItems
inner join IN_Invoices on CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId=IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId

where dbo.IN_Invoices.in_date_issued='2014-01-21 12:39:20.593'
group by cl_id
```

Instead of specifying the full date, I'd like to able to select the invoices issued in March, using something like this:

```
select dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total
from CLOI_ClientOrderItems
inner join IN_Invoices on CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId=IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId

where dbo.IN_Invoices.in_date_issued='march'
group by cl_id
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**DatePart**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp) for select the month only

```
select dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total
from CLOI_ClientOrderItems
inner join IN_Invoices on CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId=IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId

where DatePart(mm,dbo.IN_Invoices.in_date_issued)=3
group by dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
```

Comment: its showing error like Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATENAME()`:

```
select dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total
from CLOI_ClientOrderItems
inner join IN_Invoices on CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId=IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId

where DATENAME(month,dbo.IN_Invoices.in_date_issued)='March'
group by cl_id
```

Answer (score 0):

create instance for the following

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat FULL_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MM_SS_SSS_A);
```

object(FULL_DATE_TIME_FORMAT).parse("2014-01-21 12:39:20.593 Am");